# Does Keycloak Support x5* parameters in its JWK endpoint?

Tags: keycloak, x509, jwk

I'm using Keycloak as my identity and access manager.

I have a use case where I need to transmit sensitive information to another trusted party.  The flow goes like this:

- I retrieve trusted party's public key via that party's JWK endpoint
- I encrypt the sensitive data using the trusted party's public key
- I then issue a JWT token to myself.  I sign this with my private key.
- Next, I transmit the data to the trusted party, along with my JWT token in the Authorization header
- The trusted party receives my request
- The trusted party calls my JWK endpoint to get my public key
- The trusted party verifies the JWT token I sent using my public key
- The trusted party then decrypts the sensitive data using its private key

With this flow, the trusted party can be confident that

- The sensitive data was not tampered with in transit

What they cannot be confident about is:

- I am who they think I am; and I am the one that sent the data.

The only thing they know is that the endpoint they called on my side looks like it belongs to my company.  But if an adversary were to intercept requests in such a way that they returned their own public key and were able to issue their own token signed by their private key, then they could transmit any data that they wanted to the trusted party.

This is where x.509 certificates come in.  The trusted party needs a way to be certain that the party on the other end is me.

Keycloak appears to [support `x5c`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/5721/files) (certificate chain) in 5.0.0-SNAPSHOT as of four days ago; this is configured by adding/generating a new public/private key pair and a certificate.  If the certificate is configured, the `x5c` parameter is made available via the JWKS endpoint.

However, I also have a requirement to provide an `x5t` (thumbprint) parameter.  Does Keycloak provide, or intend to provide in the future, any support for this?

Answer (score 0):

I created and made the pull request for [KEYCLOAK-9868](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-9868), to add `x5t` and `x5t#S256` JWK parameters.  This has been merged to Keycloak master and should be available in whatever the next release is after 5.0.0.